# Why is the "up" in "sign-up" related to "creating a new account" but "in" in "sign-in" refers to a existing one?

Tags: adverbs, suffixes

What is the difference between *in* and *up* that causes the meaning of *sign* to change?

Research: etymonline's entries for [sign-in](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sign-in) and [sign-up](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sign-up) don't help much.

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I've added some 'research' to your question (it's expected on Stack Exchange sites to show what you've found so far). I've also added the [tag:adverbs] tag. Please feel free to [edit] further or to roll back the changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the “up” in the sign-up is related to “creating a new account” and “in” in sing-in reffers to a existing one?
>
> Whats the difference between "in" and "up" that causes the meaning of "sign" to change?

- [Sign in](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sign-in): to write your name on an official list when you arrive at a place.

  All visitors must **sign in** at the front desk.
- [Sign up](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sign-up): to agree to do something, or to join a course or organization.

  She’s decided to **sign up** for evening classes.
- [Sing in](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sing): sing to announce a coming or occurring event (New Years) or for a [group cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protest_song) such as a [sit in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sit-in).

  These are the words to Auld Lang Syne sung on Hogmanay when the bells chime and everyone crosses arms to **sing in** the new year.
- [Sing up](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sing-up): to sing with a louder voice.

  **Sing up** everyone, the people at the back can’t hear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "sing-in" was a typo in the question, but I found your answers to that interesting. :)

Comment: Mmmh, you have explained the meaning and given examples, but you haven't really given any reasons _why_ the choice of particle is related to the difference in meaning. Why is _up_ new, and _in_ existing?

Comment: -1 Sorry, I don't see an explanation in this answer for why "in" vs "up" changes the sense of "sign-X".